# What's the easiest way to get clothing

Tags: assassins-creed-identity

I am playing assassins creed identity on my iPad and what to know the easiest way to clothing, the kind that changes your appearance, in the game? Thanks for the help!

Comment: As far as I can tell, identity's clothing is bought with premium currency. Easiest way would be to buy it.

Comment: I just found out if you complete the under a red sun quest you get one.